# Choosing the right capacitors for LM2596

Tags: capacitor, switching-regulator

[image]

<sup>Picture above is from [LM2596 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM2596-D.PDF).</sup>

Is the recommended values is for fixed output voltages? If yes how to choose right capacitor value for variable output?

What's the role of I<sub>load</sub> in choosing capacitors?

My input voltage is 24V with the output voltage of 3-23V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\$C_{FF}\$ will make a zero with R2 where the zero will be at \$ \frac 1 {2\pi R_2 C_{FF}}\$

The example uses 1k for R1; that yields R2 = 3K for a 5V output and using the 5nF recommended capacitor yields a zero at about 10.6kHz

Doing the same calculation for a 9V output (R2 ~ 7.5k) and the recommended \$C_{FF}\$ of 2nF also yields a zero at 10.6kHz

From that, it seems that \$C_{FF}\$ should be \$C_{FF} = \frac 1 {2\pi R_2 10.6k} \$ where R2 is the upper part of the feedback network.

For Cout I would simply use the recommended value from the table for your Vout / Vin setup.

I do note this part of the datasheet:

> As mentioned above, a low ESR value is needed for low output ripple
>   voltage, typically 1% to 2% of the output voltage. But if the selected
>   capacitor’s ESR is extremely low (below 0.05 ohm), there is a
>   possibility of an unstable feedback loop, resulting in oscillation at
>   the output. This situation can occur when a tantalum capacitor, that
>   can have a very low ESR, is used as the only output capacitor.

This implies that an output zero needs to exist in the output capacitor as well as the feedforward capacitor; ceramic devices at the hundreds of microfarads have ESRs in the few milliohm range and might cause problems.

In this case I would use a ceramic (or a number of them to achieve the necessary Cout) in series with a 50 \$m\Omega\$ resistor (sized for the expected ripple current) in series as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvIHyg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The "General Recommendations" section of the datasheet says:

> In order to minimize the output ripple voltage it is possible … to use a larger value output capacitor.

So it is safe to use the largest capacitor (for the smallest output voltage).

As far as I can see, I<sub>load</sub> is the *maximum* output current.